# How to Mock System Class for Testing?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, integration-testing, spring-batch, spring-boot

I have a code to test which depends on the value of environment variable set.
How do I mock the setting of system environment variables??
I don't want to do System.setProperty() in my test class which may add the variable to environment.

I just want to mock the setting and test. How do I mock it??

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code really depends on a System property, I would recommend refactoring it to depend on the Spring `Environment` instead. Then you can use (with Spring Boot anyway) `@IntegrationTest` on your Spring test, e.g. (from [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications)):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
@IntegrationTest({"foo=bar"})
public class SomeIntegrationTests {

// ...

}
```

Comment: So now I have added @IntegrationTest({"SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=default"}) in one of my test class, and if I try to add @IntegrationTest({"SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=integration  "}) in my other class, that doesnt work!! It still fetches default values..

How do I handle it ?

Comment: I don't follow. What is your "other class"?

Comment: And if you want to activate a profile, just use `@ActiveProfile` on your test case.

Comment: I am writing 2 test classes seperately to test my profiles in yml file. I have 2 profiles in my yml file: default and integration

I am setting the SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE environment variable to activate my profile specific values.
So now I want to write test classes for each of the profile.

In one of my test class adding @IntegrationTest({"SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=default"}) works fine, when I write another test class and try to activate my integration profile by @IntegrationTest({"SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=integration "}) , I still get the values of my default profile.

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't very informative. Perhaps you need to ask a new question?